# how do you chain UiSelector

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator

I am having a hard time learning how to use the UiSelector class found in   android.support.test.uiautomator. I have tried several times to chain the methods but can't find a way. The last thing I tried looked like this:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('
                     new UiSelector().fromParent("
                     new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.android.app:id/content_container\")").index(1)')
```

How can I get a child object from a parent object using UiSelector? Can someone help me to understand this? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Appium I'm not sure how it goes. But on basic UIAutomator you don't have to chain new UiSelector(), you build one instance of UiSelector with chained properties.
For instance

```
UiSelector selector = new UiSelector().resourceId(<resource_id>).className(<className>).clickable(true);

UiObject object = device.findObject(selector);
```

I'm assuming you have a UiDevice.device.

You can also use BySelector and obtain UiObject2:

```
BySelector selector = By.clazz(<class_name>).res(<resource_id>);
List<UiObject2> objects = device.findObjects(selector);
```